API gateway integration with OCI Identity Domain
I am trying to get the user role from OCI IAM Identity Domain when the user login request gets passed through API Gateway. As I am new to OCI, I am looking for some help on how to approach this problem. I need to pass the user role to the downstream application which the user is trying to access.
I am thinking if we can query the Identity Domain from API Gateway to get the user role and somehow pass that to the downstream application.
